# Multilevel modeling in R - comparing models fit to different size datasets

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, missing-data, error-message

I'm running a set of multilevel models in R and want to see if adding in a predictor improves the fit of the model compared to the null/unconditional model with no predictors. When I try to run an anova command to compare the two models, I run into the following error:

```
Error in anova.merMod(nullOID, model1) : 
models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset
```

I'm a little confused as I thought one of the advantages of using multilevel modeling is that it is good at handling missing data and that you don't have to remove cases. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to get around this issue that doesn't involve removing data?

Comment: "Good for handling missing data" comes from the fact that in old-style MANOVA etc., any observations missing **within a group** (i.e., any lack of balance between groups) counts as "missing data". All values of the *predictor variables* for a given observation still need to be present ...

Comment: You could use (multiple) imputation on the missing predictor variables (admittedly this is a nuisance)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472068/force-inclusion-of-observations-with-missing-data-in-lmer

Comment: You could restrict the sample that goes into estimating the unconditional model to those observations that have a value on the predictor (i.e. are not missing it), so that when you compare the models they have the same sample